# Craft 2 FormBuilder 2 equivalent plugin in Craft 3

Tags: plugin-development, craft3, php, plugin-formbuilder2

Is there any plugin equivalent to Craft 2 FormBuilder 2 plugin in Craft 3? My Craft 2 website forms are built with FormBuilder 2. I upgraded the website to Craft 3, but FormBuilder 2 is not working. I need an equivalent plugin to work in Craft 3.

Answer (score 2):

There are a large number of form plugins in the Craft plugin store. See: https://plugins.craftcms.com/categories/forms

Some options:

- Solspace Freeform
- Solspace Express Forms
- Sprout Forms

Comment: I need a free plugin for implementation. The free version of these plugins have limitations. I need spam protection, email configuration etc. Any other free plugin available?

Comment: Not sure there are many options. Most of the major plugin developers moved to a paid model with the transition to Craft 3. So it's either buy something or spend your time to build or extend a free option.

Comment: Shall we do these forms as module and then including it in templates.? If yes, please share any tutorials are available.

Comment: Have you seen https://plugins.craftcms.com/wheelform?

Comment: Thank you. Let me look into this plugin